# Generate a sequence of random numbers

Tags: xpath, xslt, random, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to generate a sequence of random numbers using the XPath 3.1 `random-number-generator()` function.

The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-random-number-generator) states that the function returns a map containing three entries, and that the entry with key "next" is a zero-arity function that can be called to return another random number generator. However, there are no instructions (at least not instructions that I could understand) regarding how exactly to do that.

I was able, after some trial and error, to produce two **different** random numbers using:

```
<test>
    <xsl:value-of select="random-number-generator()?number" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="random-number-generator()?next()?number" />
</test>
```

However, adding a third call using the same code as the second one:

```
<test>
    <xsl:value-of select="random-number-generator()?number" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="random-number-generator()?next()?number" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="random-number-generator()?next()?number" />
</test>
```

results in the last two random numbers being equal, for example:

```
<test>0.8258447548324238 - 0.37162622506875487 - 0.37162622506875487</test>
```

(full test at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmsLza).

The specification also provides an example of *"a function that can be called to produce a random sequence of xs:double values in the range zero to one, of specified length"*. This is what I would eventually like to do, but the provided code is not in the XSLT language and I am not able to understand how it works.

Can someone please provide clear instructions how to call the function repeatedly so that it provides a **new** random number at each call?

---

### Update:

What I understand from the responses so far is that I need to use the `next()` instruction **repeatedly** on the **same** random number generator.

So that my basic example should look something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="rng" select="random-number-generator()"/>
<test>
    <xsl:value-of select="$rng?number" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$rng?next()?number" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$rng?next()?next()?number" />
</test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transcribe the XQuery code in the spec example to XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:random-sequence" as="xs:double*">
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:random-sequence($length, random-number-generator())"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:random-sequence" as="xs:double*">
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="G" as="map(xs:string, item())"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="if ($length eq 0)
              then ()
              else ($G?number, mf:random-sequence($length - 1, $G?next()))"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>{mf:random-sequence(.)}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note however, that one drawback is still that the same seed is used on each function call so repeated calls can yield the same results.

In the context of XSLT, to prevent that, I tend to use an accumulator passing the new random number generator/?next() as the value, or you can feed the generate-id of the current node as a seed to the random-number generator.

Here is an example "passing on a new random number generator/the next() one" in an accumulator, to ensure we get a new random sequence in each node (e.g. here the `data` element) we need it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:random-sequence" as="xs:double*">
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="G" as="map(xs:string, item())"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="if ($length eq 0)
              then ()
              else ($G?number, mf:random-sequence($length - 1, $G?next()))"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="rng" as="map(xs:string, item())" initial-value="random-number-generator(current-dateTime())">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="data" select="$value?next()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="rng"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>{mf:random-sequence(., accumulator-before('rng'))}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To see the advantage and difference, compare the results in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4M3Fe/1 to https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4M3Fe/0.

`fold-left` is also handy to create a sequence of random numbers e.g.

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:random-sequence" as="xs:double*">
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="rng" as="map(xs:string, item())"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="fold-left(
                1 to $length, 
                $rng, 
                function($a, $i) { 
                  let $rng := head($a) 
                  return ($rng?next(), $rng?number, tail($a)) 
                }
              ) => tail()"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4M3Fe/2

As you ask in a comment for a simpler example creating three random numbers:

```
let $rng1 := random-number-generator(current-dateTime()),
    $rng2 := $rng1?next(),
    $rng3 := $rng2?next()
return ($rng1?number, $rng2?number, $rng3?number)
```

[Online XPath 3.1 fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=let%20%24rng1%20%3A%3D%20random-number-generator%28current-dateTime%28%29%29%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24rng2%20%3A%3D%20%24rng1%3Fnext%28%29%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24rng3%20%3A%3D%20%24rng2%3Fnext%28%29%0D%0Areturn%20%28%24rng1%3Fnumber%2C%20%24rng2%3Fnumber%2C%20%24rng3%3Fnumber%29&input=&input-type=None).

Comment: Thank you for this. I am afraid I am not able to understand how these examples work. I think the problem is that they do too much. I was hoping for something much simpler that would explain the basic principle at work here. That's why my example tries to generate 3 random numbers without recursion/iteration/accumulator. If you could provide such basic example, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @y.arazim, see whether the edit (at the end) helps.

Comment: This seems to agree with what I came up with in the meanwhile (see the update to my question). If you can confirm this, I will mark this as closed.

Comment: @y.arazim, your approach is a bit different and claims you need to call the `next()` repeatedly on the same random number generator, my examples (both the simple one and the recursive one) call the `next()` function on the result of calling it on the previous one. But in the end that is perhaps just the next step to move from a specific number of explictily spelled out code to a potentially recursive function.

Comment: I don't think you're calling next() on the result. Or perhaps I misuse the word result. What I see in both cases is that an RNG is crested **once** and then "pushed" forward repeatedly. Do you see any difference between the two methods in what actually happens (as opposed to how it is initiated)?

Comment: Use whatever approach suits you and whatever description helps to understand what you are doing but certainly using e.g. `$rng3 := $rng2?next()` with `$rng2 := $rng1?next()` or the `fold-left` or the accumulator example are calling `next()` on the "previous" random number generator (map), i.e. on the initial value, then on the value created by calling `next()` on the initial value, then by calling `next()` on the previous result.

Comment: I think the difference between us is that I consider the actual random number to be the "value" or the "result". The next() is not called on that, but on something else (not sure what exactly).

Comment: It is a map having various properties, one is the `number` you are looking for, one is the `next` function you need to create the next random number generator map, one is the `permute` function.

Comment: @y.arazim, take your time to experiment but you have got some working examples now, use them as needed. Pretending your function from the link is "identical" and `xsl:iterate` sample is something you should raise in a different, new question, if you can't figure it out on your own with some more time to experiment, examine result and types of the posted examples vs the one you have written.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
<xsl:iterate select="1 to $limit">
  <xsl:param name="generator" select="random-number-generator()"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$generator?number || ', '"/>
  <xsl:next-iteration>
     <xsl:with-param name="generator" select="$generator?next()"/>
  </xsl:next-iteration>
</xsl:iterate>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to be the cleanest and most elegant approach of all suggested so far, at least for generating a single sequence. For multiple sequences,  I suppose I could make this a function and call it with a seed parameter, e.g. current datetime + position * 100nS.

Comment: Yes, but you need to be careful using current-dateTime as a seed, because it's constant over the transformation.

Comment: That is why I would add 100nS at each call.